# AsyncTask return variable cannot be resolved

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask

What's wrong with this AsyncTask code that prevents it returning an array progress... I get "progress cannot be resolved to a variable" on the noted line.

```
public class FetchProgress extends AsyncTask<OpportunityActivity, Void, ArrayList<Progress>> {
private OpportunityActivity opportunityActivity;

@Override
protected ArrayList<Progress> doInBackground(OpportunityActivity... activity) {
    opportunityActivity = activity[0];             
    String readFeed = readFeed();
    // this JSON feed is delivered correctly

    try {       
       JSONObject json = new JSONObject(readFeed);                 
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json.optString("ShowProgress"));

          Progress progress = new Progress();
          progress.setShowProgress(jsonObject.getBoolean("ShowProgress"));
          progress.setTarget(jsonObject.getInt("Target"));

     // the above values are set correctly and appear if I use Log            

    } catch (Exception e) {    
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   // HERE'S THE ISSUE: 
   // Eclipse reports "progress cannot be resolved to a variable"
   return progress;
}
```

Here's the OnPostExecute:

```
public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Progress> progress) {
     opportunityActivity.updateProgress(progress);
}
```

Here's the class:

```
public class Progress {
private boolean showprogress;
private int target;

public boolean getShowProgress() {
    return showprogress;
}
public void setShowProgress(boolean showprogress) {
    this.showprogress = showprogress;
}

public int getTarget() {
    return target;
}

public void setTarget(int target) {
    this.target = target;
}
}
```

Here's the onPostExecute:

```
public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Progress> progress) {
     opportunityActivity.updateProgress(progress);
}
```

And the method it triggers where I can't access the passed ArrayList:

```
public void updateProgress(ArrayList<Progress> progress) {      
    progress_text  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.progress_text);          
    progress_text.setText("Target: " + progress.getTarget());
}
```

Comment: You should learn the basics of Java first : http://mindprod.com/jgloss/scope.html

Answer (score 2):

Cut this line,

```
 Progress progress = new Progress();
```

and paste it out of try statement.

```
ArrayList<Progress> progressArray=new ArrayList();

  Progress progress = new Progress();

try {       
       JSONObject json = new JSONObject(readFeed);                 
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json.optString("ShowProgress"));


          progress.setShowProgress(jsonObject.getBoolean("ShowProgress"));
          progress.setTarget(jsonObject.getInt("Target"));
       progressArray.add(progress);
     // the above values are set correctly and appear if I use Log            

    } catch (Exception e) {    
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   return progressArray;
```

Since you have declared and initialized it within the try Catch it is not visible to your method.

**EDIT**

But still it would be wrong since it is just a object of class you are trying to return but whereas your method would expect a ArrayList of type  to be returned. So I have edited my answer on how you should return a ArrayList.

Comment: If I move the line `Progress progress = new Progress();` outside of the try statement then I get a new error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Progress to ArrayList<Progress>" for my `return progress`; line.

Comment: Thanks - now the array isn't getting passed through to the onPostExecute and ultimate method that acts on this (see updated code).
How can I correctly transfer and then access the passed array variables.

Comment: The editor liked `ArrayList<Progress> progressArray=new ArrayList<Progress>();`  
This said I am still not able to access the array in my onPostExecute method updateProgress. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andro (who will be getting added reputation).

I finally accessed the values in the array using this loop (which seems needless) but it finally got the elements out of this one dimensional array:

```
   for (Progress i : progress) 
   progress_text.setText(i.getOrange() + " / " + i.getTarget() + " hours");        
    progressHours.setMax(i.getTarget());
    progressHours.setProgress(i.getOrange());           
    }
```

I'd welcome comments on whether adding this second dimension is necessary.